# Run an external program in C# (cross-platform)

Tags: c#, .net, mono, cross-platform, system.diagnostics

I have already seen System.Diagnostics, but I can't seem to figure out how to do what I want.

The user specifies what program they want run. On Windows systems this would be something like "C://path/to/someProgram.exe", but on a linux system something like "/usr/bin/wine start /path/to/someProgram.exe" would be passed instead.

My program passes additional parameters to the specified and runs it.

What can I do that will run on both windows and linux systems?

Comment: Well, on Linux you'll need to make sure that your PATH environment variable has the location of `wine` in it, and I assume you'll need to give `wine` the full path to someProgram.exe.  What error messages are you getting?

Comment: @adv12 You are correct about the path, I have added that to the main post. The problem is that running programs using system.diagnostics the program and parameters must be specified separately. In the windows the executable is "someProgram.exe" with no parameters, but in the linux example the executable is "wine", with parameters "start /path/to/someProgram.exe". I have seen examples of passing the entire command as a parameter to "sh", but this only works on linux systems.

Comment: You can check Environment.OSVersion.Platform to determine is it Windows or Linux and branch your parameters